# increment/decrement listview selected position on notifydatachanged

Tags: android, listview

Hi! I'm trying to add some values in listview , and trying to increase/decrease  the quantity of items using (inc) and (dec) buttons .

To increase or decrease list view item quantity, I have to select the list row, if I add any item in it .

How to increment/decrement listview selected position on notifydatachanged?
Right now i am doing like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    index = position;

}
```

getting the selected index here and using this index value to increase or decrease item quantity

Comment: use `setSelection (int position)` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)

Comment: @Dev Soman Yes i am using custom adapter for setting list items

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` is filled up with the dataset you provided to the adapter. If you want to increase/decrease the item the ListView shows, you have to add/remove item from this dataset and invoke `notifyDatasetChanged()`